# I am trying to have a listbox in a user form that when i select an specific list item i want a text box to be visible

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a list box in a userform VBA that when i select a specific list item I want a text box to be visible

Comment: Show the code for the "I am trying" part please.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/tour and how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to refine your question. As it is it won't get responded. Showing your work and your thoughts about the problem is a good way to show what you already tried. Hope this helps.